# Yii2: Not able to Update multiple Images

Tags: php, yii, yii2

In controller

```
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

         if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
        { 
            $imageName = $model->room_type;
            $model->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles');
            $all_files_paths = [];
                 foreach ($model->imageFiles as $file_instance) 
                 {
                   $path = 'uploads/room_img/' . $file_instance->baseName . '.' . $file_instance->extension;
                   $file_instance->saveAs($path);
                    $all_files_pathes []= $path;
                    $model->images .= $path . ';';
                 }
            $model->save(false);
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
 }

        else 

        {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

in rules section

```
[['imageFiles'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 4,'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'on' => 'update-photo-upload'],
```

tried using `scenario` but it returning to view with no changes in images.

Uploading multiple image file and storing path in database like

```
uploads/room_img/1059.jpg;uploads/room_img/1060.jpg;uploads/room_img/1064.jpg;
```

Im inserting multiple files in database separated by `;`, not able to update the path of the image

actioncreate()

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new RoomTypes();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
        { 
            $imageName = $model->room_type;
            $model->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles');
            $all_files_paths = [];
                 foreach ($model->imageFiles as $file_instance) 
                 {
                   $path = 'uploads/room_img/' . $file_instance->baseName . '.' . $file_instance->extension;
                   $file_instance->saveAs($path);
                    $all_files_pathes []= $path;
                    $model->images .= $path . ';';
                 }
     $model->save(false);
     return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
 }
        else 
        {
            return $this->render('create', 
                [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you load a single image  the update work?

Comment: yes its working on single image but not on multiple

Comment: How you get the image name .. show the related view and explain how you work/use this view

Comment: image names are already there application does not generate new name

Comment: Then you have a string like "uploads/room_img/1059.jpg;uploads/room_img/1060.jpg;uploads/room_img/1064.jpg;" .. and you want update the value ... ? but the value contain more than one name or you want store different name in different rows?

Comment: I want to update the image replacing `"uploads/room_img/1059.jpg;uploads/room_img/1060.jpg;uploads/room_img/1064.jpg;"` with new updated image files

Comment: I have posted an  answer ....hope is useful ..

Comment: I have delete the answer .. beacuse i don't have undertand  right your question.. i'm sorry

Comment: image names are already there like it generated  by camera, so im only uploading to the server with no change in image name, so I want to update all images

Comment: have you understood the question ?

Comment: no I'm sorry I cannot understand your question

Comment: ok, I want to update the multiple images, when user create record it upload multiple images for that record along with record name, address, etc. its getting uploaded successfully. and can see all record details  in view. but when user try too update any particular image from multiple uploaded files its not able to update.

Comment: You use a widget for upload the image during create   ?  ..

Comment: yes kartik fileinput

Comment: in you update you don't perform the model->uploadImage ...youn should show your related model and also your actionCreate ...

Comment: i have updated the question please have a look

Comment: If you want upload multiple image files in update you should code like you deed in actionCreate ..  UploadedFile ... and loop for store di image ..

Comment: i tried that as well, but its appending the files not replacing the old files, i can see old files as well as new files that i have updated

Comment: i need to use `unlike` function to delete the old files, but problem here im facing is not able to get single file name as im uploading multiple files

Comment: But you obtain the sequence of the files like  "uploads/room_img/1059.jpg;uploads/room_img/1060.jpg;uploads/room_img/1064.jpg;‌​"  right?   where is the problem for delete the old files?

Comment: yes in database its like this `"uploads/room_img/1059.jpg;uploads/room_img/1060.jpg;uploads/room_img/1064.jpg;‌‌​​"` only, need to use `unlike` to delete files from the server otherwise it will be pile of files residing on server with no use, consuming space

Comment: Ok but if you have the list of files form your model what's the problem for delete the old files.. because seems only this the question at this point ..

Comment: the way you suggested to code like `actioncreate()` I did in `actionupdate()` but its not updating the old files instead its  appending the new files along with old files

Comment: I have posted an asnwer hope this is useful ..

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->scenario = 'update-photo-upload';

    $oldFiles = explode( ";", $model->imageFiles);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

       foreach ($oldFiles as $actFile)  {

               if (trim($actFile) != '') {
                 unlink( 'uploads/room_img/' . $actFile);
               }
        } 

        $model->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles');
        $all_files_paths = [];
             foreach ($model->imageFiles as $file_instance) 
             {
               $path = 'uploads/room_img/' . $file_instance->baseName . '.' . $file_instance->extension;
               $file_instance->saveAs($path);
                $all_files_pathes []= $path;
                $model->images .= $path . ';';
             }
    $model->save(false);
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } 

    else 
    {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: getting this error `syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '('` at `foreach ($oldFiles as actFiles)  {
           // delete the old files ..

        } `

Comment: I have update the answer    ... exchanged param in explode .. but i hope you understand the suggestion ..

Comment: Found $actFiles  ... not actFiles

Comment: its not removing older files instead adding files to the database

Comment: Have you placed proper instruction for remove the old files ? .. i just posted a comment ...

Comment: In my code there is only a commen //delete the old files .. have you added the proper code for remove the files fromd the server ?

Comment: i wrote this `if ($imageFiles !== false && unlink($oldFile)) 
           {
                    $path = $model->imageFiles();
                    $imageFiles->saveAs($path);
                }`

Comment: Are you sure about the correct path for unlink .. the explode just give you the filename not the fullpath ..

Comment: ya path is correct as mentioned `$path = 'uploads/room_img/'`

Comment: can you tell me what ever i wrote to delete the files is right?

Comment: can you help what to write in `// delete the old files ..`

Comment: Ok removed the actFiles in actFile

Comment: unlink(uploads/room_img/): Permission denied

Comment: Is your server  ..  check your permission  ond the related dir check also if the last actfile is empty (could be)

Comment: using xampp on windows 10, windows in not restricted about write permissions but dont know whats wrong with it, I will let you know about this :)

Comment: Could be there is an empty value at the end of array then ... i have update the answer ..

Comment: its not deleting the old files(path mentioned in db), it should overwrite the path with new file path in db?

Comment: sure the path is correct ? try var_dump the   'uploads/room_img/' . $actFile in the foreach and check

Comment: yes here is the full path `C:\xampp\htdocs\NewHotel\advanced\backend\web\uploads\room_img`